# $Ax=0$ in a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

I am self-studying Linear Algebra, mainly through Khan Academy and some YouTube videos. I have encountered the following problem.

---

Given

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 & -2\\ 
-4 & 2 & 4\\ 
-8 & 4 & 8 
\end{bmatrix}$$

how can I find the solutions of $Ax = 0$? And how could these solutions be a linear combination of two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$?

---

As I tried reducing the matrix by the Gauss method and got $0$'s. I am quite confused as to what to do. Are there any videos that could explain this? Thank you for any help. When I reduced it with the Gauss method, I got the following:

[image: My attempt]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you reduced the matrix, you can do an extra step and divide the first row by $2$.
Then every row of zeros represents a free variable. So let $x_2=s$ and $x_3=t$, with $s,t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now go back to a system of equations and you get $x_1-\frac{1}{2}x_2-x_3=0$, i.e. $x_1=\frac{1}{2}x_2+x_3=\frac{1}{2}s+t$. Therefore the solutions of the system are of the form
$$
\pmatrix{\frac{1}{2}s+t \\
s \\
t
}
$$
or
$$
\pmatrix{\frac{1}{2}s \\
s \\
0
}+\pmatrix{t \\
0 \\
t
}=s\pmatrix{\frac{1}{2}\\
1 \\
0
}+t\pmatrix{1 \\
0 \\
1
}
$$

Comment: Ooh, wow, thank you very much. I am flabbergasted. I think some of these things are still a bit abstract and fascinating to me. Thank you! I shall analyse it carefully and try to understand the meaning of it.

:)